# Маршрутиризация между .vue компонентами

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Создал проект в webpack, создал несколько .vue фалов.
Подключаю их через main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import 1 from './views/1.vue'
import 2 from './views/2.vue'

new Vue({
el: '#app',
  render: h => h(1)
})
```

Как теперь из 1.vue переключиться в 2.vue ? :)
Не как не могу понять каким образом вызвать `render: h => h(2)`
И по хорошему еще бы передать ему аргументы

Comment: Разобрался. Не правильно выбрана архитектура. И ушел читать https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 8):

Возможно вам нужен [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/essentials/getting-started.html)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- используйте компонент router-link для создания ссылок -->
    <!-- входной параметр `to` определяет путь для перехода -->
    <!-- <router-link> по умолчанию преобразуется в тег `<a>` -->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- отображение компонента, для которого совпал путь -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

JS

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }    
const routes = [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // сокращение от routes: routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Я разбирался не так давно со всем, вот можете смотреть в моём репозитории как и что, буду рад правкам. : https://github.com/Shleif91/vuex-example